# Update excel sheets from SQL Server 2005 linked servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server, excel

I use SQL Server linked servers to connect to Excel 2003 multiple tabs workbook. After connected, I have not problem to use select statement like:

```
select * FROM OPENQUERY(TEST, 'select * from [fist day$]')
```

but I can not use normal delete and insert statement. I want to delete data from first row and insert one row of data into the last row to the excel spreadsheet.

I use:

```
delete top(1) FROM OPENQUERY(TEST, 'select * from [first day$]')
```

and I get

> *OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "TEST"
>   returned message "Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by
>   this ISAM.".*
>   *Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 1*
>   *The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "TEST" could not delete
>   from table "select * from [first day$]". There was a recoverable,
>   provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure.*

Comment: Is this referring to the same issue as you've asked about here(http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/how-to-copy-data-from-mssql-table-to-excel-spreadsheet-thru-linked-servers)